# washer drain pipe through triple stud

Tags: plumbing

Bit of a predicament here. Previous owner converted a part of the garage into a laundry room and installed a sink. The faucet fed the sink and also was connected to the cold/hot washer hoses, while the washer drain tube drained directly into the sink basin. While replumbing the house, I thought to install a washer outlet box with water lines tee'd off from the sink lines, and tie in new drainage w/p-trap as well. However I found that in the 2' space between the sink location and where the washer outlet box needs to go, there is a triple vertical stud. I believe this used to be the wall separating the kitchen and garage (now there's a wall between kitchen and laundry, and between laundry and garage), and don't know if triple stud = load bearing.

I was able to drill 1" holes for the pex piping. But from what I've read I cannot drill a 2.5" hole for 2" ABS drain pipe into a 2x4 stud, let alone a double or triple stud, because it exceeds the 60% limit (40% if load bearing).

Is there any scenario where this works?

I cut out the existing p-trap and will tie in a wye with p-trap coming out the wall to the sink, and a second wye below that heading towards the washer outlet with a p-trap... but studs are in the way.

[image]

Photo found on terrylove (not my exact setup) showing drilling through more than triple studs with nail plates. Doesn't seem up to code, or safe -- look at the how thin the stud walls are in the bottom braces!

[image]

Comment: The nail plates are to protect the pipes, not to provide strength. There are a whole bunch of rules somewhere, but I think generally you want to limit holes to about 1/3 the width of a stud or joist and keep it roughly centered.

Comment: That's what I thought too, so the terry love photo seemed like stud strength was not addressed. My plan is to drill a 2 1/2" hole with a hole saw extension, then use a triple stud shoe. Please let me know if that sounds like a good or bad idea!